# Terraform Error: ClientException: When the volume parameter is specified, only one volume configuration type should be used

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I use terraform to create multiple tasks definitions and one of these tasks definitions has multiple volumes but when I try to create from this error, is it possible to create multiple volumes in a task by terraform? because by aws it is possible. But the terraform shows this error.

**Error: ClientException: When the volume parameter is specified, only one volume configuration type should be used**

I searched the entire internet to find this problem and didn't find an answer, as I'm already using the dynamic volume equal to this in the terraform documentation.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = "~> 3.0"
  }
}

variable "task_definition_names" {
  type = any
  default = [
    {
      task_definition_name = "jenkins"
      task_definition_file = "jenkins-task-definition.json"
      shared_memory_size   = 64
      cpu                  = 0
      memory_reservation   = 3900
      entrypoint           = ""
      ecr_repository_name  = "jenkins:lts"
      dns                  = "jenkins.com.br"
      hosted_zone          = ""
      allowed_volumes      = true
      volume = [
        {
          name      = "efs-jenkins"
          host_path = "/var/jenkins_home"
          efs_volume_configuration = [{
            file_system_id     = "fs-"
            root_directory     = "/"
            transit_encryption = "ENABLED"
            authorization_config = [{
              access_point_id = "fsap-"
              iam             = "ENABLED"
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          name                     = "docker-sock"
          host_path                = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        },
        {
          name                     = "docker-bin"
          host_path                = "/usr/bin/docker"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      task_definition_name = "staging-api"
      task_definition_file = "staging-api-task-definition.json"
      shared_memory_size   = 64
      cpu                  = 0
      memory_reservation   = 900
      entrypoint           = ""
      ecr_repository_name  = "staging-api"
      allowed_volumes      = false
      volume               = []
    }
 ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "main" {
  count  = length(var.task_definition_names)
  family = var.task_definition_names[count.index].task_definition_name

  container_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/${var.task_definition_names[count.index].task_definition_file}", var.task_definition_names[count.index])

  dynamic "volume" {
    
    for_each = var.task_definition_names[count.index].volume
    content {
      host_path = lookup(volume.value, "host_path", null)
      name      = volume.value.name

      dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
        for_each = lookup(volume.value, "efs_volume_configuration", [])
        content {
          file_system_id          = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "file_system_id", null)
          root_directory          = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "root_directory", null)
          transit_encryption      = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "transit_encryption", null)
          transit_encryption_port = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "transit_encryption_port", null)
          dynamic "authorization_config" {
            for_each = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "authorization_config", [])
            content {
              access_point_id = lookup(authorization_config.value, "access_point_id", null)
              iam             = lookup(authorization_config.value, "iam", null)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This script is for create multiple task-definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using awscli, but removing any references to `host` and `host_path` in the configuration resolved it for me.

Comment: `name` is required ( at least since provider 3.0.0) but removing `host_path` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you want to do, but you can have **only one** `efs_volume_configuration`. However you are trying to create multiple instances of `efs_volume_configuration` as a dynamic block:

```
dynamic "efs_volume_configuration"
```

Also whatever you do in the console, must be related to something else, or AWS console makes it seem like you can do it. But under hood, you **can't do this**.

Comment: No, I tried to create 3 volumes but only one have one efs_volume_configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this fails is because you can only specify a docker volume or a bind mount as per the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html

and

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html

In your example above, I do not think you can have `host_path` in conjunction with  the dynamic block `dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {`

If you remove `host_path` (which is bind mount specific), it should work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30169758)